# TOP clause slowing down query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 queries: one with a TOP clause and one without. The result is the exact same yet the one with the TOP clause is significantly slower.  Why would that be?

**Server:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

**Query 1** - *Regular*

```
insert into #Buffer (details, persistentID, productID, [date])
select de.details, lg.databaseID % 1000, lg.productID, lg.readDateTime
from Log lg with (nolock)
join LogDetails de with (nolock)
    on lg.logID = de.logID
where @startDate <= readDateTime and readDateTime < @endDate
```

- *CPU time*: 173,640 ms
- *Elapsed time*: 34,700 ms
- **[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By9ZcaSQg)**

**Query 2** - *TOP clause*

```
insert into #Buffer (details, persistentID, productID, [date])
select top (@count) de.details, lg.databaseID % 1000, lg.productID, lg.readDateTime
from Log lg with (nolock)
join LogDetails de with (nolock)
    on lg.logID = de.logID
where @startDate <= readDateTime and readDateTime < @endDate
```

Note `@count` is the size of the result set.

- *CPU time*: 92,953 ms
- *Elapsed time*: 93,732 ms
- **[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1hou6Hmg)**

Oddly, the CPU time of Query 2 is half that of Query 1, and yet the elapsed time of Query 2 is 3 times that of Query 1.

Comment: because now it has to order the results

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? I would guess the `TOP` query doesn't use an index where the other query does,

Comment: @Lamak Will it though? No `order by` is given, won't it just return the `top` results in whatever order they come in (ie arbitrarily)?

Comment: Where is your `order by` statement to support your `top`?

Comment: @SqlZim I don't need to order the results since the `@count` is the size of the result set

Comment: @HoneyBadger there's no "order the come in", it needs to order the results or use an index for it

Comment: @JamieLester then why would you use `TOP`?

Comment: @Lamak sorry to haress you, but on what predicate will it order if no `order by` is given?

Comment: @Lamak the log table is 100 million rows but I only want to select a fraction of it.

Comment: Compare the execution plans.

Comment: Far as I know, `TOP x` without an `order by` will return an arbitrary set (hence I'm curious what @Lamak means the set is ordered anyway)

Comment: Take a look at the execution plans. It is going to be sorting by something even if you don't specify something in `order by`

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) top without an order by *"...returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order"*.  But in any case including TOP generates extra work for SQL.

Comment: @SqlZim What would you suggest that 'something' is (assuming there is no index or PK (for argument's sake))

Comment: How can I post the Execution plan?

Comment: @JamieLester https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/how-and-why-does-top-impact-an-execution-plan/24848#24848

Comment: The execution plans are now included.

Comment: Looks like the `top` operator is nudging the plan to use nested loops instead of the hashmatch join, so instead of doing two scans it's doing 1 scan and a seek for each row in the scan; and you lost your parallelism. @MartinSmith's link to Paul White's answer explains why.

Comment: @SqlZim so I added `option (hash join)` to the TOP query which has sped it up by 35%

Comment: @JamieLester Still wondering why you are using `top` when you are returning the full result set. Glad you got the performance boost!

Comment: @SqlZim so that it doesn't scan the entire table looking for more rows that match the search predicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this :[Inside the Optimizer: Row Goals In Depth](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx) from [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white)

When you present a query to SQLServer,it  assumes, you will be consuming all rows produced by the query .But *some times* ,when you introduce TOP and EXISTS operators ,SQL server will try to find the First Row as soon as possible,this some times will lead to lesser optimal plan.In your case,it lead to Nested Loops Plan..

You may ask why this row Goal ,can't be optimized..Below is the explanation from Paul White for the same..

> The challenges involved in producing an optimised query plan for row-limited queries, while retaining good general optimisation performance for full-result queries, are more complex than simply replacing hash or merge join iterators with nested loops.  It would be reasonably straightforward to cater for queries with a TOP at the root of a plan, using specific code designed to recognise specific scenarios.  However, that approach would miss wider opportunities for plan optimisation in more general cases.
>
> **The TOP clause can be specified multiple times, in multiple places in a query declaration: in the outermost scope (as in the example); in a sub-query; or in a common table expression – all of which may be arbitrarily complex**.  The FAST ‘n’ query hint can also be used to ask the optimiser to prefer a plan which will produce the first ‘n’ rows quickly, while not restricting the total number of rows returned overall, as is the case with TOP.  As a final example, consider that a logical semi-join (such as a sub-query introduced with EXISTS) shares the overall theme: it should be optimised to find the first matching row quickly.
>
> The SQL Server query optimiser provides a way to meet all these requirements by introducing the concept of a ‘row goal’, which simply establishes a number of rows to ‘aim for’ at a particular point in the plan.

So in your case,to overcome this `ROWGOAL` Limitation,you can rewrite query like below,by using a hint

```
insert into #ViewCountBuffer (details, persistentID, productID, [date])
 select top (@count) details, databaseID % 1000, productID, readDateTime
 from Log ld with (nolock)
 HASH join LogDetails de with (nolock)
  on ld.logID = de.logID
 where @startDate <= readDateTime and readDateTime < @endDate
```

Below are related threads on stack Exchange on same topic,..

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157353/wrapping-query-in-if-exists-makes-it-very-slow

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126235/if-exists-taking-longer-than-embedded-select-statement

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/how-and-why-does-top-impact-an-execution-plan

Comment: I added `option (hash join)` to the query which sped it up, but ultimately removed the TOP clause